# Propositional Logic Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

how to prove this statement using propositional logic. The idea is in my head but i just can't seem to figure it out. Here is the statement : 
(A->B)^(B->(C->D))^(A->(B->C))->(A->D)

This is what i've got so far

1. A->B  (hyp)
2. B->(C->D)       (hyp)
3. A->(B->C)       (hyp)
4. A               (hyp,DM)
5. B->C            (3,4,MP)

Comment: Which proof system are you supposed to use? There are many different proof systems for propositional logic, which have quite different character. At this level, a proof that works in one of them will not be of much use if you're supposed to use different one.

Comment: I am supposed to use formal logic proof

Comment: x @EDDY: I'm asking you **which kind** of formal logic proof you're supposed to produce. As I said, there are many different proof systems for propositional logic, which have quite different character. At this level, a proof that works in one of them will not be of much use if you're supposed to use different one.

Comment: i'M not sure i understand what you mean but i'm guessing it's inference rules??? Not sure

Comment: SORRY IF I'M not understanding

Comment: x @EDDY: Yes, you have to show the inference rules and axioms in order to get help with proving your goal using the particular inference rules and axioms you have, rather than a different system that has other inference rules and axioms.

Comment: Please refrain from using caps lock, especially in titles.

Comment: If you have *modus ponens* and the *Deduction Theorem*, it's enough  that you use the ausiliary assumption $A$ (your 4) to "detach" $B$ from 1; with $B$ you detach $C$ from 5. With $B$ and $C$ you detach $D$ from 2 and finally, with the *Deduction Theorem*, you "discharge" the auxiliary assumtion $A$ getting $A \rightarrow D$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

The problem, as I understand it is to prove CKKCabCbCcdCaCbcCad.  The notation Ko indicates a use of conjunction elimination.  Co indicates a use of detachment (or modus ponens).  Ci indicates the use of conditional introduction.

```
1  KKCabCbCcdCaCbc  hypothesis
2  a                hypothesis
3  KCabCbCcd        1 Ko-left
4  CaCbc            1 Ko-right
5  Cab              3 Ko-left
6  CbCcd            3 Ko-right
7  Cbc              4, 2 Co
8  b                5, 2 Co
9  c                7, 8 Co
10 Ccd              6, 8 Co
11 d                10, 9 Co
12 Cad              2-11 Ci
```

A consequence of the deduction metatheorem here tells us that for the system {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CKpqp, CKpqq} under detachment and uniform substitution CKKCabCbCcdCaCbcCad is a theorem.